# How to make my project build automatically by clicking a button on the front-end

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, npm, inertiajs

I'm making a custom CMS for a client. They want the possibility to change all the text in the app. After changing some fields, the app needs to rebuild. I'm using Laravel x vue x Inertia

This is my code

```
<template>
    <form :action="route('cms.store')" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" :value="lang" name="lang">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrf">

        <div class="flex flex-row items-center gap-2">
            <button type="submit" class=" bg-bgDark px-5 py-2.5">Sla op</button>
            <button @click="sync()" class="bg-bgDark px-5 py-2.5">Synchroniseer</button>
        </div>

        <TabWrapper>

            <TabItem
                v-for="(value, key) in json"
                :id="key"
                :label="key"
            >

                <div v-for="(value2, key2) in value" :key="key2" class="flex flex-col min-w-max">
                    <label :for="value2"> {{ camelCase(key2) }}</label>
                    <input class="bg-bgLight border-bgDark p-4 mb-5" type="text" :name="key + '--' + key2" :value="value2">
                </div>

            </TabItem>

        </TabWrapper>

    </form>
</template>

<script>
import TabItem from '../Tabs/TabItem.vue';
import TabWrapper from '../Tabs/TabWrapper.vue';
import { exec } from 'child_process';

export default {
    props: {
        json: Object,
        languages: Object,
        lang: String,
    },
    methods: {
        camelCase(value) {
            value = value.replace(/([A-Z])/g, " $1");
            value = value.replace(/^ /, "");
            value = value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
            return value;
        },
        sync() {
            exec('npm run build', function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
            console.log('build has started')

        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            csrf: document.querySelector("meta[name=\"csrf-token\"]").getAttribute("content"),
        };
    },
    components: { TabWrapper, TabItem }
}
</script>
```

As you can see I tried it with child.process. I also tried it with node-cmd package but that ain't working to

Comment: I believe `exec` will be run on client side, while you want to run from the server side. Perhaps you could rebuild from Laravel when you submit the form using [Process](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/processes) Component? Response time may take a while though. If response time matters, you can use a [Queue](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues) to rebuild asynchronously.